# why we need the contravariance in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've learned a lot from the [post](https://kt.academy/article/ak-variance) talking about kotlin generic variance modifiers, but I have a small question. I didn’t notice any **obvious advantage** in using the contravariance, say we have code like this

```kotlin
interface Message

interface OrderManagerMessage : Message

interface InvoiceManagerMessage : Message


class Order {}

class OrderManagerMessageImpl : OrderManagerMessage {}

class InvoiceManagerMessageImpl : InvoiceManagerMessage {}

class AddOrder(val order: Order) : OrderManagerMessage {}

class CancelOrder(val orderId: String) : OrderManagerMessage {}

class MakeInvoice(val order: Order) : OrderManagerMessage

class Connection(val url: String) {
    fun send(msg: Message) {}
}

interface Sender<in T : Message> {
    fun send(message: T)
}

class GeneralSender(serviceUrl: String) : Sender<Message> {
    private val connection = Connection("")

    override fun send(message: Message) {
        connection.send(message)
    }
}

fun main() {
    val orderManagerSender: Sender<OrderManagerMessage> = GeneralSender("orderManagerURL")
    orderManagerSender.send(OrderManagerMessageImpl())
    
    val invoiceManagerSender: Sender<InvoiceManagerMessage> = GeneralSender("invoiceManagerURL")
    invoiceManagerSender.send(InvoiceManagerMessageImpl())
}
```

we can do the same thing without contravariance, we can change code to

```kotlin
 interface Sender<T : Message> {
    fun send(message: T)
 }

 class GeneralSender<T : Message>(serviceUrl: String) : Sender<T> {
    private val connection = Connection("")

    override fun send(message: T) {
        connection.send(message)
    }
 }

 fun main() {
    val orderManagerSender: Sender<OrderManagerMessage> = GeneralSender("orderManagerURL")
    orderManagerSender.send(OrderManagerMessageImpl())

    val invoiceManagerSender: Sender<InvoiceManagerMessage> = GeneralSender("invoiceManagerURL")
    invoiceManagerSender.send(InvoiceManagerMessageImpl())
 }
```

Just add `<T : Message>` to the class `GeneralSender`. So can someone explain what the flaws are in this modified code?

[playground](https://pl.kotl.in/vqBgufNxb)

Answer (score 4):

We need contravariance to allow using more generic consumers in the more specific context. Your example is actually great to show this!

Imagine we have an order manager service, which needs to send `OrderManagerMessage` messages, so it needs a sender: `Sender<OrderManagerMessage>`. We have a more generic sender: `Sender<Message>` which can handle any type of `Message`, including `OrderManagerMessage`. There is no reason our order manager can't work with this generic sender, but without contravariance it actually won't be able to do this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val generalSender = GeneralSender<Message>("orderManagerURL")
    val orderManager = createOrderManager(generalSender)
}

fun createOrderManager(sender: Sender<OrderManagerMessage>) {}
```

Please use this code with both variants of your samples. You will notice the code works correctly with contravariance, but not without it.

Comment: Is it correct to say that contravariant and covariant type parameters also prevent compile-time errors?

Comment: @Steyrix Hmm, I don't think this is correct. Default variance (invariant) is the most strict, it doesn't at all allow to cast the `T` to any other type. Covariance and contravariance loosen this requirements by allowing `T` to be either subtyped or supertyped. But the compiler still guarantees the type safety.

Comment: Great answer! but I think the concept of contravariance itself is counterintuitive. when you say "We have a more generic sender: Sender<Message> which can handle any type of Message, including OrderManagerMessage" , actully you broadened the scope. I mean `Sender<OrderManagerMessage>` is expected, but you pass a `Sender<Message>` type and it's hard for me to accept that such behavior is safe and reasonable.

Comment: Why do you think it is not safe or reasonable? `Sender<Message>` means it consumes messages, no matter their type. If it would be able to consume only specific types of message, it should be typed accordingly.

Comment: If we have a `Sender<Message>` we can freely call its `send()` function passing the `OrderManagerMessage` as argument. But we can't pass it to a function/object which would like to... call its `send()` function passing the `OrderManagerMessage`. We can't do this until we make it contravariant.